# Matplotlib Graphing

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I need to graph two sets of 100 dots each. 
The first set of dots goes along the Y axis, and the next set of dots is a bit further away from the first set of dots.

My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data= numpy.array(network)      #network is a list of values
datatwo= numpy.array(list)      #list is another list
cmap= numpy.array([(1,0,0),(0,1,0)])
uniqdata, idx=numpy.unique(data, return_inverse=True)
uniqdata, idx=numpy.unique(datatwo, return_inverse=True)

N=len(data)
M=len(datatwo)
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(numpy.zeros(N), numpy.arange(1,N+1), s=50, c=cmap[idx])
plt.scatter(numpy.ones(M), numpy.arange(1,M+1), s=50, c=cmap[idx])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

My problem is that the two lists, network and list, have different values, but the interpreter graphs the same set of dots two times. I need to have two different sets of dots, one for network and list, respectively.

what is wrong with the code?
Thanks

Comment: Minor comment `matplotlib.pyplot at plt` should be `as` not `at`

Comment: Well, for starters, you aren't using `data` or `datatwo` in your plot calls at all.  You're just plotting their lengths (i.e., if `data` is of length 3, you plot [1, 2, 3] as the y values, regardless of what the actual values of `data` are).  Also, you're overwriting `idx` immediately after you create it.

Comment: you should not use `list` to name a variable, but is may not solve your problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working piece of code that will plot on the unique values contained in 2 lists, with the first set located along the Y-axis and the second at Y=1 using different colors for each respective list.  I'm guessing that because you are using `np.unique` the two lists contain repeated values that you don't want to plot more than once.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
####################################################################################

network = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,9,10] # Some lists of values
ilist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,10]  # Some other list of values


data= np.array(network)      #network is a list of values
datatwo= np.array(ilist)      #list is another list

# Some list of color maps to color each list with
cmap= np.array([(1,0,0),(0,1,0)])

# Get the unique values from each array
uniqdata1, idx1=np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)  
uniqdata2, idx2=np.unique(datatwo, return_inverse=True) 

# Find the length of each unique value array
N=len(uniqdata1) 
M=len(uniqdata2)

# Plot the data
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(np.zeros(N), uniqdata1, s=50, c=cmap[0])
plt.scatter(np.ones(M), uniqdata2, s=50, c=cmap[1])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps